# router interface list reading through ssh and python script to read traffic over a particular interface

Tags: ssh, bandwidth, network-interface, netmiko

Hello everyone، I am new to python and netmiko. I want to read multiple interfaces on a Cisco router to monitor live traffic's by using python script through a netmiko ssh connection.

There should be three steps 1, ssh 2,read interface list 3, read interface traffic

Comment: Stack Overflow is neither a code writing service nor a replacement for basic documentation and tutorials. Please show us the code you've written so far and explain where you're having difficulties and we'll try to help out.

Answer (score 0):

Example of using the Netmiko library to establish an SSH connection to a Cisco IOS device, retrieve interface information using the 'show interfaces' command, and parse the output using NTC templates.

```py
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
from ntc_templates.parse import parse_output

# Define the device details
device = {
    "device_type": "cisco_ios",
    "ip": "10.0.0.1",
    "username": "username",
    "password": "password.",
}

# Establish SSH connection
ssh = ConnectHandler(**device)

# Send command to retrieve interface list
output = ssh.send_command("show interfaces")
print(output)
# GigabitEthernet0/0/0 is up, line protocol is up
#   ...
#   30 second input rate 4000 bits/sec, 2 packets/sec
#   30 second output rate 94000 bits/sec, 52 packets/sec
#
# GigabitEthernet0/0/1 is up, line protocol is up
#   ...
#   30 second input rate 3590000 bits/sec, 449 packets/sec
#   30 second output rate 123000 bits/sec, 160 packets/sec
# ...

# Input rate, and output rate are printed for each interface.
parsed_output = parse_output("cisco_ios", "show interfaces", output)
for data in parsed_output:
    print("{interface} {input_rate} {output_rate}".format(**data))
# GigabitEthernet0/0/0 4000 94000
# GigabitEthernet0/0/1 3590000 123000
# ...
```

Comment: Dear, your answer is very simple. You have uploaded  a ssh connection and then simply you passed a command show interface. Similar to show up interface or show up int brief. These commands don't show real time traffic. Infact my question is regrading real time traffic bandwidth monitoring and getting traffic stats for every sec. Receive 10kb, Sent 2kb, total 12 kb. With a timestamp 2023-04-01 10:12:43